# WPF routed events handling in UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, routed-events

I have a WPF UserControl that contains a button. I also have a WPF Window that contains a button.
In both the UserControl and the Window I place the following line in XAML:

```
UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
```

and in 'OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown' I've place a debug print that displays args.Source.

When I click on the button that is inside the window, I get the button as the EventArgs source. However, when I click the button that inside the UserControl (which is also inside a window, so I could test it, but not the same window) I get the UserControl as the EventArgs source.

I tired to see if there is some decorator around the UserControl (using snoop) but it seems straight forward.

I can't understand what is so special about UserControl in WPF that I don't get the right sender. Can someone please explain to me what am I missing?

Comment: Use `e.OriginalSource`... thats always the actual source element which raised the routed event.

Comment: Problem with e.OriginalSource is that it gives me the inner-most visual-tree-level control, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the control (as in "button") itself, rather than it's inner "chrome" or "textblock".

Comment: Where is your `UIElement` Style defined at? And does it mark the event as `Handled`?

Comment: I have no style definitions, and I do not touch the EventArgs rather than getting the Source from them, so I do not change the "Handled" property. Don't know if the default style is doing it, but since I do get the event (just with wrong source) I don't think the default style/codebehind is touching the Handled property either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question is old, I recently ran into a similar problem myself, involving the ContextMenuOpening event. Some amount of searching yielded the source code to UserControl [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/UserControl@cs/1/UserControl@cs), which contains the following section:

```
    // Set the EventArgs' source to be this UserControl 
    internal override void AdjustBranchSource(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Source=this;
    }
```

So, apparently UserControl sets the Source of ANY routed event to itself. I have no idea why it does this, though...

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.OriginalSource` as mentioned above. If you need to find the button, then you can use `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` to find the actual Button control.